# Remove whitespace with xslt after merge with xsi:nil="true" element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an two xml files that I merge together with xslt 1.0.  Many elements in the second file have the xsi:nil="true" attribute and appear something like this

```
<my:DoorType xsi:nil="true"></my:DoorType>
```

After merging the two files with my xslt that looks like below, the resulting xml is generated with a space in it. I need to remove the spaces so the DoorType element is present but with no value. I prefer to do this in the same xslt file and not in an independent one.

```
<xsl:template match="my:DoorType">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file:\\\C:\Users\template.xml')/my:DoorType/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Actual result

```
<my:DoorType xsi:nil="true"> </my:DoorType>
```

Desired result

```
<my:DoorType xsi:nil="true"></my:DoorType>
```

Comment: Please provide a (short) way for us to reproduce the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: That's very difficult due to the complexity of my files.

Comment: Then produce a simplified example.

Comment: I don't see why the code as posted would create any `xsi:nil` attribute at all as you do not copy it nor create it. Are the input elements you process really empty, without any child contents? All the `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file:\\\C:\Users\template.xml')/my:DoorType/*" />` processing any child elements does not make sense. Perhaps you simply need e.g. `<xsl:template match="my:DoorType[@xsi:nil = 'true']"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.